# How can I integrate fancybox with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am new in **angular js**. so when i see a example to know how to integrate **fancy box** with angular then few confusion arise due to weak hold on angular.

i was reading a code sample from this link http://embed.plnkr.co/y02UMQ2kU4fh8Imsa82u/

just like to know about few line like what they does.

```
app.directive('fancybox', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      $scope.open_fancybox = function() {

        var el = angular.element(element.html()),

        compiled = $compile(el);

        $.fancybox.open(el);

        compiled($scope);

      };
    }
  };
});
```

below these lines are not clear.

```
var el = angular.element(element.html()),
compiled = $compile(el);
$.fancybox.open(el);
compiled($scope);
```

1) what $compile does and what it return after compile ?
2) when we need to compile scope like compiled($scope);

i have test the if i comment this line `compiled($scope);` then value is not putting into expression.......why ?

please guide me in detail. thanks

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: which tag you talking about?

Comment: [The one I removed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44136103/revisions)